# Rotate CSS3 e Tabelas

Tags: css3

Estou utilizando dados tabulares em uma tabela e algumas informações com 90 graus (em pé) nas células. Porém o css não se comporta como o esperado e deixa espaços grandes como se o texto estivesse normal na horizontal. Alguém sabe de alguma propriedade que resolva isso?

Segue link [aqui](http://drop.studiogt.com.br/its/index.php/produto-filtro) para ver como ficou. Apenas coloquei :

```
 p {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
```

Comment: Acho que ajudaria bastante se você mostrasse o trecho de código CSS pertinente e o resultado atual, dsantoro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jeito é forçar a largura na marra. Adicione:

```
width: 20px;
```

Ao parágrafo.

Note que isso faz com que o texto suba um tanto. Para corrigir, é preciso adicionar uma margem acima. Consegui uma boa margem para o seu caso específico com 170 pixels... Outros casos podem precisar de outras medidas. Experimente também com medidas não fixas depois, pois assim terá algo mais reutilizável. O CSS completo do parágrafo fica mais ou menos assim:

```
p {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20px;
    margin-top: 170px;
}
```

Comment: Opa. Isso ajudou bastante ein. Tamo quase lá. Descobri algo sobre isso, esse "issue". Segue link http://www.benknowscode.com/2014/01/css-rotated-text-parent-dimensions-and-spacing-issues.html

Comment: Valeu pelo link! Não costumo usar rotações, mas isso despertou bastante minha curiosidade!

Comment: Também não costumo usar mas as vezes o trabalho nos obriga rs.

Answer (score 0):

Parte da culpa pode ser da definição padrão da propriedade `Display` para elementos `P`.

Tente o seguinte:

```
 p {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

Um Fiddle de demonstração [pode ser visualizado aqui.](http://jsfiddle.net/1y5gqt6a/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O Fizzdle não ta abrindo rs. Mas não resolveu. Não sei se é algo na tabela ou no p. Acho que o CSS não da preparado pra isso.